# Как используя nmpjs конвертировать JPG base64 в webp base64 или же прямо в файл?

Tags: javascript, node.js, изображения, base64, jpeg

Конвертирую картинку **JPG** формата в **WEBP** формат.

Поставил **npmjs** модуль https://www.npmjs.com/package/webp-converter на **node 18.**

Поставил в перем [[PYT]] -  путь к jpg файлу вот такой:
C:\Users\username\Downloads\777\1c.jpg

Но в переменную[[ITOG]] не сохраняется ничего (она пустая).

И использую из офиц доков такой пример для:
**Convert base64 image to webpbase64 image**

```html
        const webp=require('webp-converter');
    const fs=require('fs');
    const path=[[PYT]];
    function get_webpbase64(path) {
    fs.readFile(path, function (error, data) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      } else {
        let buf = Buffer.from(data);
        let dataBase64 = Buffer.from(buf).toString('base64');
          // base64str of image
        // base64str image type jpg,png ...
        //option: options and quality,it should be given between 0 to 100
        let result = webp.str2webpstr(dataBase64,"jpg","-q 80");
        [[ITOG]]=result;
        result.then(function(result) {
          // you access the value from the promise here
              console.log(result)
            });
      }
    });
    }
    // use the default temp path for conversion
    get_webpbase64("./nodejs_logo.jpg")
    // use the custom temp path for conversion
    get_webpbase64("./nodejs_logo.jpg","/home/user/Desktop/webp/temp")
```

Но в переменную [[ITOG]] не сохраняется ничего (она пустая)

Comment: Это что вообще `[[ITOG]]=result;` где это в документации? Слеши не экранированы `C:\Users\username\Downloads\777\1c.jpg`  Зачем это `get_webpbase64("./nodejs_logo.jpg") get_webpbase64("./nodejs_logo.jpg","/home/user/Desktop/webp/temp")` ?

Comment: в моем софте переменные сохраняются в двойных квадратных скобках на подобии этого: [[ITOG]]  , в эту переменную должен сохраниться результат в виде строки с base64 кодом.

C:\Users\username\Downloads\777\1c.jpg -  это пусть к файлу который записан в переменную [[PYT]] .
Я пробовал экранировать слеши записав в [[PYT]] эту строку C:/\Users/\username/\Downloads/\777/\1c.jpg  , но так же [[ITOG]] остаётся пустым

Comment: В доках написано `// использовать временный путь по умолчанию для преобразования get_webpbase64 ( "./nodejs_logo.jpg" ) // использовать собственный временный путь для преобразования 
get_webpbase64 ( "./nodejs_logo.jpg" , "/home/user/Desktop/webp/temp" )`  Какой смысл лепить всё подряд? То что `webp.str2webpstr(..` возвращает Promise это очевидно. Этот путь вообще существует `"/home/user/Desktop/webp/temp"` ? Экранирование слешей `\\\`

Comment: спасибо получилось)